# How to get colors made by color scale of conditional formatting of Excel 2012 through VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, colors, conditional-statements, formatting

I need to know: **how to get colors made by color scale of conditional formatting of Excel 2010 throught VBA code**. Those colors will be subsequently assigned by VBA as chart background according to the following image:

[www.lnkm.cz/Slozka/Example.jpg http://www.lnkm.cz/Slozka/Example.jpg](http://www.lnkm.cz/Slozka/Example.jpg)

I did a research on various web sides and:

1. Most people advice how to read color of conditional formatting by method 
   `<Cell>.FormatConditions(index that is active).Interior.ColorIndex` 
   but in my case it don’t work because of error “Object doesn’t support this property or method”
2. Some people advice to write own computation of colors (based on cells value). I found various ways how to do it, but none of them can compute same colors as was computed previously by excel (same colors as are on previous picture).

So I’m asking:

1. Is there any way to directly ready colors from cells? (or those colors are not accessible for API)
2. Do you know how to compute same colors as excel compute?
3. Do you know any other way how to solve my problem?

I believe that it has to work somehow.

Comment: Do you have a specific code sample you are trying to work through? Not completely clear on what you are trying to do. It is easy to read colors directly from cells like `oSheet.Range("A1").Interior.Color` or `oSheet.Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex`. Perhaps there is some other bug in the code that we can help with.

Comment: For your 'Object' error on point #1, you need to set your cell to something first. Either reference it directly, (e.g. `ActiveSheet.Range("A1")>.FormatConditions(SomeVariable).Interior.ColorIndex`) or `SET` it as a variable (e.g. `Set MyCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")`)

Comment: Hi Gaffi, thanks for your reply, but I already did. I set by various cell by various ways (SET function, selected cell etc.). I put after .FormatConditions(SomeVariable) others command which was already working. So I think that "FormatConditions" dont know "interior"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if no better answer is provided, you can try this workaround:

1. link / copy your data to cells under the chart (with formulas like `=Sheet1!A1`)
2. apply the same conditional formatting
3. hide the values (with custom number format like `""`, i.e. empty string literal (2 double quotes))
4. make the chart transparent
5. align the cells with the chart

---

**UPDATE**:

or you can try to compute the color by linear approximation for each R, G, B channel if the conditional format uses only 2 base colors (r1, g1, b1) and (r2, g2, b2) for 2 corner cases which can be

- `min` and `max` **value**, e.g.: 0 - 4 000
- `min` and `max` **percent**, e.g.: 10% - 90% 
   (i believe you can use % * [max_value - min_value] to get the actual value)
- `min` and `max` **percentile**, e.g.: 0th percentile - 100th percentile

for percent / percentile options you first need to convert an actual value to the percent / percentile value, then if `value < min` or `value > max` use the corner colors, otherwise:

```
r = r1 + (r2 - r1) * (value - min_value) / (max_value - min_value)
g = ...
b = ...
```

Comment: Hi deathApril, nice idea, but I simplify explanation in my question. In the fact I need to add in to each left top corner of every chart small rectangle (shape in excel terminology) with color of conditional formating and its value. If it will be backgroud of chart, it makes imposible to observe chart points of dark purple cases. but you idea was inspirating.

Comment: if you had your chart white except the small rectangle areas in left top corner shapes... but no, it won't work for retrieving 'its value' :(

Comment: i updated my answer, but the computation is just my educated guess, i don't have excel here to test it..

Comment: Ive try your update. Colors are not same than excel condition formatting. But the bigger matrix, less obvious difference in colors. I’ll try if it acceptable for my purposes and let you know if it is solved.

Answer (score 2):

This will copy a picture of a cell to the top-left corner of a chartobject on the same worksheet.  Note the picture is linked to the copied cell - if the value or formatting color changes it will change to match.

```
Sub Tester()

    CopyLinkedPicToPlot ActiveSheet.Range("E4"), "Chart 2"

End Sub

Sub CopyLinkedPicToPlot(rngCopy As Range, chtName As String)

    Dim cht As ChartObject

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chtName)

    rngCopy.Copy
    With rngCopy.Parent.Pictures.Paste(Link:=True)
        .Top = cht.Top
        .Left = cht.Left
    End With

End Sub
```

EDIT: I just tested this with a fairly small 4x8 matrix of cells/charts and the performance is pretty bad!  Might be better just pasting without Link:=True ...

Comment: Ive try this solution, but there is problem with performance. For my purpose I need change parameter with name "NPHR" (orange one on previous picture) and observe changes in "purple formated area" and "group of charts" (on left and righr part of picture). Both contains huge amout of data (excel file has 90 MB) and one change of parameter NPHR takes 0,5s second for "purple formated area" and 2,5s for "group of charts". Once I copy just one cell as yoiu advice it takes cca 6 seconds, I gues that it will be definetly wery slow for all necesary cells.

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to your problem but is easily modified to solve your problem...

```
Sub CopyCondFill()
    Dim FromSheet As Object
    Dim ToSheet As Object
    Dim FromSheetName as String
    Dim ToSheetName as String
    Dim ToRange As Range
    Dim StrRange As String

    '''Sheet with formatting you want to copy
    FromSheetName = "YourSheetsName"
    Set FromSheet = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(FromSheetName )
        '''Start of range within sheet you want to copy
        FromFirstRow = 3
        FromFirstCol = 2

    '''Sheet you want to copy formatting to
    ToSheetName = "YourSheetsName"
    Set ToSheet = Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ToSheetName)
        '''range to copy formatting to
        ToFirstRow = 3
        ToFirstCol = 2
        '''NOTE: Adjust row/column to take lastrow/lastcol from or enter value manually
        ToLastRow = FromSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ToLastCol = FromSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set ToRange = ToSheet.Range(Cells(ToFirstRow, ToFirstCol), Cells(ToLastRow, ToLastCol))

        '''Apply formatting to range
        For Each cell In ToRange
            StrRange = cell.Address(0, 0)
            ToSheet.Range(StrRange).Offset(ToFirstRow - FromFirstRow, ToFirstCol - FromFirstCol).Interior.Color = _
                FromSheet.Range(StrRange).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
        Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Cell>.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
```

This should word with Excel later than 2010.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, based on the answer of JKirchartz

```
Sub copyBackgroundColors(source As Range, target As Range)
    target.Interior.color = source.DisplayFormat.Interior.color
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a partial answer to your question.  Column 1 of the table below lists Excel's standard 40 colours.  Columns 2, 3 and 4 list the red, green and blue components of each colour.  So if you want a cell's font to be light orange:

```
Cell(Row, Column).Font.Color = RGB(255, 153, 0)
```

If you try any other red-green-combination, Excel will match it to the nearest one of these standard colours although Excel's idea of "nearest" does not match mine.

Hope this helps if you get the other part of your question answered.

```
Colour                Red  Green   Blue
Black                   0      0      0
Light orange          255    153      0
Lime                  153    204      0
Gold                  255    204      0
Bright green            0    255      0
Yellow                255    255      0
Grey 80%               51     51     51
Dark teal               0     51    102
Plum                  153     51    102
Sea green              51    153    102
Dark blue               0      0    128
Dark red              128      0      0
Violet                128      0    128
Teal                    0    128    128
Grey 50%              128    128    128
Grey 40%              150    150    150
Indigo                 51     51    153
Blue-grey             102    102    153
Tan                   255    204    153
Light yellow          255    255    153
Grey 25%              192    192    192
Aqua                   51    204    204
Red                   255      0      0
Rose                  255    153    204
Light green           204    255    204
Blue                    0      0    255
Pink                  255      0    255
Light blue             51    102    255
Lavender              204    153    255
Sky blue                0    204    255
Pale blue             153    204    255
Turquoise               0    255    255
Light turquoise       204    255    255
Dark green              0     51      0
White                 255    255    255
Olive green            51     51      0
Brown                 153     51      0
Orange                255    102      0
Green                   0    128      0
Dark yellow           128    128      0
```

Comment: I think that Excel 2007 is less prone to snapping colors to the pallette than prior versions. Eg:  see http://www.databison.com/index.php/excel-color-palette-and-color-index-change-using-vba/

Comment: @Tim. Thanks for the information, I will have to try. I performed the experimentation that resulted in the above list seven or eight years ago and I have never had reason to revisit it. Since I am so careful to stick to this list, I had not noticed that Excel 2007 was better at handling colours than 2003.  Always good to learn something new.  I am also pleased that a list of Excel's colours is available on the internet now; there was nothing similar that I could find when I needed it.

Comment: @Tony where'd you find this list? source?

Comment: I created my list by experimentation. I coloured cells and then read Cells.Interior.Color.  If you search the web for "Excel colour palette" you will find any number of sites containing this information,